# How to see the DOM generated by javascript using htmlunit?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, htmlunit

I have got an html page in which the UI is generated using javascript.I am interested in a form which is visible when the page is inspected using developer tools but not in html source.
In htmlunit i tried to wait for the javascript to execute and then print it as Xml but DOM elements are not seen!!How can i do this??Please help

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with Java, but Javascript perhaps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the changed HTML content after it's updated by Javascript? (htmlunit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521/get-the-changed-html-content-after-its-updated-by-javascript-htmlunit)

Comment: @MostyMostacho No it doesn't.What i get is the Javascript code not the generated html ,that is exactly my problem

Comment: @MostyMostacho Javascript doesn't change the content once the site is loaded ,and they generate some forms using Javascript and send the content to the server for validation

Comment: In your question you say `UI is generated using javascript`. In your comment you say the opposite: `Javascript doesn't change the content once the site is loaded`. And later in your comment you say the original statement again: `they generate some forms using Javascript`. I'm not sure what to think. Anyway, the linked question should have all the information you need

Comment: @MostyMostacho I am Sorry what i  meant was Javascript changes the content only at the loading time ,later on the page remain static no change in the page

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: @jack No .the site  i was inspecting generates a lot of forms during the loading time using javascript .the form data is sent in the post requests the page make.

Answer (score 2):

`HtmlPage.getDocumentElement().asXml()`

This can be tested using

```
System.out.println(page.getDocumentElement().asXml());
```

on

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="lj">
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("lj").innerHTML = "Foo";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

will show

```
<div id="lj">
Foo
</div>
```