# HtmlUnit wait for onclick event

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I have this web code:

```
<a id="btn">Click</a>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
         $('#btn').click(function() {
             ...
             location.search = $.params({click: '1'});
         });
    });
</script>
```

This code work perfectly in Chrome.

But I want to test it with HtmlUnit. I wrote:

```
    page= (HtmlPage) ((HtmlAnchor) page.getDocumentElement().querySelector("#btn")).click();
    assertThat(page.getUrl().getQuery(), containsString("click=1"));
```

This code works randomly. Sometime the test passed and sometimes failed.
I think it is due because of the asynchronous call to JS, but I couldn't solve it.

So how can I test it?

*Besides, there is better solution to test web site insted HtmlUnit? HtmlUnit disappointed...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your code *works randomly* might mean that there is a timing issue in the asynchronous JS call. I have explained the best alternative to come around these kind of issues in this other question: [Get the changed HTML content after it's updated by Javascript? (htmlunit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521)

Answering your second question, HtmlUnit is a pain in the neck when it comes to JS. Maybe Selenium with the native browser (eg: IE) drivers are a better alternative. Plan C would be [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) but it is not a Java library.

Comment: Good point. I assumed you were performing an AJAX call in your `...`. Either way, if it is asynchronous then you can handle it the same way. Now I see what might be the issue: `location.search` is performing another HTTP request. So you should wait for the request to finish. Again, this should be handled as I explained in the other question by applying a manual delay

Comment: No, in the `...` code its just for setting variables. No more actions do in this function.

Answer (score 0):

I fell also in similar issue. My html link is triggering javascript using events.

My not working test code was:

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = element.getFirstByXPath("//a[@id='...']");
anchor.click(); // This is not firing events on js side!!!!
```

How it works:

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = element.getFirstByXPath("//a[@id='...']");
anchor.fireEvent("click"); // JS running which listening on click events!
```

Comment: Michael - can you please open an issue on Github for your case. anchor.click() should definitly trigger the events. Do you use a rect version?

Comment: Hi @RBRi, I am using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf and JQuery.

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/301