# Getting web page source code in Java

Tags: java, javascript, firebug

I use Java. I want to get web page source code but on the page works JavaScript and I want get code generated by JavaScript (code which we see in firebug in firefox)
Anyone knows what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

To inspect the page after modification by JavaScript, you need a client-side JavaScript engine that can run the scripts and then let you inspect the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can do this - it is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs".

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521/get-the-changed-html-content-after-its-updated-by-javascript-htmlunit)

However, this won't give you the exact original page source, because that has already been parsed into a DOM by this point.

Comment: You don't need a "client-side" JavaScript engine.

Comment: @meagar Can you elaborate, please? *Something* needs to execute the JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to see the source code of DOM Elements created after the page load via AJAX.

If that´s what you want, the only way to see it is through a DOM inspector, like firebug in firefox or Developers Tools in Chrome. 
Going to "View source code" only shows the source at load-time.

Comment: Is it impossible to get this in JAVA? Maybe in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, yes your javascript objects can be passed back to your java backend either by a creating a html `<form>` element with `input`elements, fill them with your values and then submit the form, or asynchronously via ajax/json (which doesn't require re-loading your web page). For both methods you need to configure an endpoint on your java side to receive the submitted data and return some kind of confirmation to the client, i.e. your javascript. I would recommend googling "jQuery.post" for the javascript side and finding some examples for your java backend.